# why can't I use HoughCircles inside a python function?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I can't get HoughCircles to run inside of a function...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def test(image):
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 4, 70, minRadius=70, maxRadius=74)
    if circles is not None:
        circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    for x, y, r in circles:
        cv2.circle(image, (x, y), r, [0, 0, 255], 2)
    return image
img = cv2.imread('initial_frame.png')
image2 = test(img)

cv2.imshow('test', image2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This results in ...

```py
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(image, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 4, 70, minRadius=70, maxRadius=74)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.3) C:\Users\runneradmin\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-1i5nllza\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\hough.cpp:2253: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'cv::HoughCircles'
```

If I remove the call to `HoughCircles`, then `image2` is shown as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About interpreting the error. It comes from [hough.cpp#L1659](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.1/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp#L1659):

```
CV_Assert(!_image.empty() && _image.type() == CV_8UC1 && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()));
```

Breaking it down, all the following conditions have to be true:

- `!_image.empty()`: the input image should not be empty;
- `_image.type() == CV_8UC1`: the input image must be `8U` (8-bit unsigned, `np.uint8`) and `C1` (single-channel);
- `_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()`: check if the input is `Mat` or `UMat` (in Python, it has to be a numpy array);

The issue that is affecting you is you can only call `cv2.HoughCircles()` on a single-channel (greyscale) image, your image has 3 channels. Convert your image to greyscale and then try again.

Comment: Arrrrgghhh.... Thank you.  Can't believe I asked the question.  Must need to take a break here.

Comment: No problem! Please select this as the answer if it helped.